# The leaves on my huge oak tree are being eaten by caterpillars

Tags: trees, oak

If all the leaves on my ancient huge oak tree are eaten by caterpillars, will the tree still survive? What can I do to save it?
At this point in time I feel absolutely helpless. Please, if anybody knows what to do, let me know. I can not watch this tree dying. [image][image][image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the caterpillars and a detail of the leaf so we can tell what kind of oak?  Where is the oak tree located, what part of the world?  Is this the first time the caterpillars have shown up or is this a yearly thing?

Comment: Yes,the tree will survive, even if all the leaves get eaten, but please provide the information asked for in the previous comment - in particular, what do the caterpillars look like and where are you in the world?

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond. Yes, it is happening for the first time. We live in Canada. Just wondering, how this kind of big tree can be protected from any kind of insects.